# Burlando encurtadores com python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Eu necessito para meu projeto, alguma função usando **Python 2.7** que entre em um URL, e pegue o URL seguinte dele.
-> Exemplo:
goo.gl/LAKFXG = https://pt.stackoverflow.com/
bit.ly/2D3SEnZ = https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Não quero usar o API destas URLS, e sim algo que realmente entre na url e me devolva a URL final. Porém, estou sem ideias.
Alguma biblioteca? Lembrando que não quero usar as API de encurtadores.

Comment: Como não trabalho com Python, vou deixar uma dica que talvez lhe ajude. Utilize o comando `cURL` do Python para acessar essa url. Porém, ao invés de retornar o "body", você retorna apenas os "headers". Tendo os headers, basta filtrar por *location*, *followlocation*, etc.

Comment: O que está a implementar é algo do tipo _URL unshortener_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import urllib2
r = urllib2.urlopen(url="https://shorturl.com")
print 'URL redirecionada:', r.url
```

Comment: urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
O que faço neste caso?

Comment: Qual URL você tentou?
Segundo os códigos de estado, isso é um erro de proibição: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_códigos_de_estado_HTTP#403_Proibido

```>>> r = urllib2.urlopen(url="https://goo.gl/LAKFXG")
>>> r.url
'https://pt.stackoverflow.com/'```

Comment: Não os headers. Qual URL você tentou? Para que eu possa replicar o erro.

Comment: Heey! Consegui acabar com o erro. 403 forbidden! pastebin.com/5tyzikbD
Obrigado frank!

Comment: Agora man. Eu aconselharia fortemente o uso da biblioteca requests e python3. Se você não tiver com algum projeto em ambiente de produção claro.

Comment: Em que o requests + python3 atrapalharia ambientes em produção @FranklinTimóteo ?

Comment: Ele está utilizando python2, o que eu quis dizer é que ele pode trocar para python3 e usar a biblioteca requests, porém se ele estiver usando python2 com projeto em produção, concorda que seria difícil fazer essa troca da noite para o dia? A questão é: mude para python3 o mais rápido possível, mas se já utiliza python2 e não quer perder tempo com retrabalho, continue com python2 até ter tempo para fazer a devida modificação.

Comment: A própria documentação do urllib2 recomenda o uso de requests. https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html . Ahh mas isso é só para obter uma URL final, porque usar uma biblioteca mais robusta? Verdade, não faz sentido. Mas se pensarmos no futuro onde você queria aprimorar seu programa?!